# $f \in L_2$ bandlimited implies $f$ equal to continous function a.e. (without using Parley-Wiener)

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was wondering, if my proof is right as I didn't find any similar statements in books or the internet without using the Parley-Wiener-Theorem:
If we have $f \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$, bandlimited (i.e. supp$(\mathcal{F} f) \subseteq  [-\lambda, \lambda]$ ), then $\mathcal{F} f$ is in $L_1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L_2(\mathbb{R})$ (in $L_2$ per Definition of the $L_2$-Fourier Transform and in $L_1$ because of bounded support).
The invers $L_2$-Transform $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F} f=f$ a.e therefore coincides with the invers $L_1$-Transform a.e. But the propertys of the (invers) $L_1$-Transform imply $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F} f\in L^{\infty}$ uniformly continous. We can conclude, that $f$ is a.e. equal to an uniformly continous function.

Comment: There is nothing in your problem statement that prevents changing $f$ on a set of measure $0$, and still having the same conditions met. $f$ will be equal a.e. to a uniformly continuous function in $L^{\infty}$. I believe that is correct. Of course the $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ applied to a band-limited function gives you an infinitely differentiable function that is the restriction to the real axis of a power series of exponential order that converges everywhere in the complex plane. The latter condition is Paley-Wiener.

Comment: Ok if I understand you right, there is just the "almost everywhere" missing in my the statement, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I see: "almost everywhere" is needed to be precise. Everything else looks good, and you can go further, which is why I mentioned the power series stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I edited my post. Yes, I know the additional properties.